# How do I alter myuserpoints table?

Tags: userpoints

I am using the Userpoints module. Using that, when I click the "My Score" link I am viewing a table with list of points.

There are 6 headers and 6 rows displaying. In that table, I need only 3 headers and 3 rows to display.

As of now, the module shows the following headers:

- Points
- Approved
- Date
- Operation
- Category
- Description

What I need to display is the following headers:

- Points
- Date
- Description

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the way:

> hook_menu_alter()

```
/**
 *Implemantation of hook_menu_alter()
 */
function your_module_menu_alter(&$items) {
  $items['myuserpoints']['page callback'] = 'userpoints_list_my_userpoints_custom';
}
```

By using menu alter write your custom function and change the table structure as per your need. And it's done :)